# How are values ​received from the user assigned to variables received from the user?

Tags: c++

> I am doing a project that it names is book suggestor. User will select
> pages,subject and price and program will show suggestions but i have
> problems about user decisions for example i want to select pages
> [0-50] but after i select it is not assinging.How can i solve this
> problem?
> Should i use switch case or if statements. If i use if else stamements how i can use it?

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;
    
    class BookShop{
    
    protected:
        int usertema;
        int userfiyat;
        int usersayfaaraligi;
    
    public:
        int tur;
    
        void Karsilama(){
            cout<<"Hosgeldiniz secmek istediginiz türü seciniz"<<endl;
            cout<<"1:modern klasik \n 2:Turkedebiyati \n 3:Dunyaklasigi";
            cin>>tur;
        }
    
    };
    
    
    class ModernKlasik:public BookShop{
    public:
        ModernKlasik()
        {
            cout<<"Aradiginiz kitap temasi nedir?";
            cout<<"\n1:Korku\n2:Aşk\n3:Sevgi\n4:Dram\n5:Kahramanlık\n";
            cin>>usertema;
            cout<<"Sayfa sayisi?:";
            cout<<"\n1:[0-50]\n2:[50-100]\n3:[100-200]\n4:[200-300]\n5:[400-500]\n6:[500+]";
            cin>>usersayfaaraligi;
            cout<<"Fiyat araligi?:";
            cout<<"\n1:[0-10]TL\n2:[10-20]TL\n3:[20-50]TL\n4:[50-75]TL\n5:[75-100]TL\n6:[100+]TL";
            cin>>userfiyat;
        }
    
        void fonksiyon1(){
    
        ofstream myFile1("Modernklasik.txt");
        myFile1<<"Kitap1:Tema= ,Sayfa sayisi=50,Fiyat=6 TL,Adý=Mecburiyet(Stefan Zweig)"<<endl;
        myFile1<<"Kitap2:Tema= ,Sayfa sayisi=70,Fiyat=8 TL,Adý=Feniçka(Lou Andreas-Salome)"<<endl;
        myFile1<<"Kitap3:Tema= ,Sayfa sayisi=74,Fiyat=8 Tl,Adý=Ayýþýðý Sokaðý(Stefan Zweig)"<<endl;
        myFile1<<"Kitap4:Tema= ,Sayfa sayisi=108,Fiyat=11 TL,Adý=Vahþetin Çaðrýsý(Jack London)"<<endl;
        myFile1<<"Kitap5:Tema= ,Sayfa sayisi=150,Fiyat=20 TL,Adý=Hayvan Çiftliði(George Orwell)"<<endl;
        myFile1<<"Kitap6:Tema= ,Sayfa sayisi=256,Fiyat=15 Tl,Adý=Karmaþýk Duygular(Stefan Zweig)"<<endl;
        }
    };
    
    class Turkedebiyati:public BookShop{
    public:
        Turkedebiyati()
        {
            cout<<"Aradiginiz kitap temasi nedir?";
            cout<<"\n1:Korku\n2:Aşk\n3:Sevgi\n4:Dram\n5:Kahramanlık\n";
            cin>>usertema;
            cout<<"Sayfa sayisi?:";
            cout<<"\n1:[0-50]\n2:[50-100]\n3:[100-200]\n4:[200-300]\n5:[400-500]\n6:[500+]";
            cin>>usersayfaaraligi;
            cout<<"Fiyat araligi?:";
            cout<<"\n1:[0-10]TL\n2:[10-20]TL\n3:[20-50]TL\n4:[50-75]TL\n5:[75-100]TL\n6:[100+]TL";
            cin>>userfiyat;
        }
    
        void fonksiyon2(){
        ofstream myFile2 ("Turkedebiyati.txt");
        myFile2<<"Kitap1:Tema= ,Sayfa sayisi=409,Fiyat=20 TL,Adý=Çalýkuþu(Reþatnuri Gültekin)"<<endl;
        myFile2<<"Kitap2:Tema= ,Sayfa sayisi=164,Fiyat=5 TL,Adý=Kürk Mantolu Madonna(Sabahattin Ali)"<<endl;
        myFile2<<"Kitap3:Tema= ,Sayfa sayisi=112,Fiyat=8 Tl,Adý=Dokuzuncu Hariciye Koðusu(Peyami Safa)"<<endl;
        myFile2<<"Kitap4:Tema= ,Sayfa sayisi=112,Fiyat=5 TL,Adý=Vatan Yahut Silistre(Namik Kemal)"<<endl;
        myFile2<<"Kitap5:Tema= ,Sayfa sayisi=300,Fiyat=10 TL,Adý=Eylül(Mehmet Rauf)"<<endl;
        myFile2<<"Kitap6:Tema= ,Sayfa sayisi=195,Fiyat=12 Tl,Adý=Kýrmýzý Sacli Kadin(Orhan Pamuk)"<<endl;
        }
    
    };
    
     class Dunyaklasikleri:public BookShop{
     public:
         Dunyaklasikleri()
         {
            cout<<"Aradiginiz kitap temasi nedir?";
            cout<<"\n1:Korku\n2:Aşk\n3:Sevgi\n4:Dram\n5:Kahramanlık\n";
            cin>>usertema;
            cout<<"Sayfa sayisi?:";
            cout<<"\n1:[0-50]\n2:[50-100]\n3:[100-200]\n4:[200-300]\n5:[400-500]\n6:[500+]";
            cin>>usersayfaaraligi;
            cout<<"Fiyat araligi?:";
            cout<<"\n1:[0-10]TL\n2:[10-20]TL\n3:[20-50]TL\n4:[50-75]TL\n5:[75-100]TL\n6:[100+]TL";
            cin>>userfiyat;
          }
    
          void fonksiyon3(){
          ofstream myFile3 ("Dunyaklasikleri.txt");
          myFile3<<"Kitap1:Tema= ,Sayfa sayisi=592,Fiyat= TL,Adý=Suç ve Ceza(Dostoyevski)"<<endl;
          myFile3<<"Kitap2:Tema= ,Sayfa sayisi=393,Fiyat= TL,Adý=Savaþ ve Barýþ(Tolstoy)"<<endl;
          myFile3<<"Kitap3:Tema= ,Sayfa sayisi=464,Fiyat= Tl,Adý=Ýki þehrin hikayesi(Charles Dickens)"<<endl;
          myFile3<<"Kitap4:Tema= ,Sayfa sayisi=184,Fiyat= TL,Adý=Ýnsancýklar(Dostoyevski)"<<endl;
          myFile3<<"Kitap5:Tema= ,Sayfa sayisi=128,Fiyat= TL,Adý=Fareler ve Ýnsanlar(John Steinbeck)"<<endl;
          myFile3<<"Kitap6:Tema= ,Sayfa sayisi=240,Fiyat= Tl,Adý=Romeo ve Juliet(William Shakespeare)"<<endl;
          }
    
    };
    
    int main()
    {
        BookShop b1;
    
        b1.Karsilama();
    
        if(b1.tur==1)
        {
            ModernKlasik m1;
            m1.fonksiyon1();
    
        }
        if(b1.tur==2)
        {
            Turkedebiyati t1;
            t1.fonksiyon2();
        }
        if(b1.tur==3)
        {
            Dunyaklasikleri d1;
            d1.fonksiyon3();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I need help please

Comment: All inputs are correctly stored in the member variables. What exactly is your problem. Which selection combination causes problems. Using if and or switch should not make any difference.

Comment: How to Read from txt file. I want to write books on txt file and im my program i select some decisions for example program ask me what kind of book would you like to read (history,worlds classics etc..)and program read from txt and show suggestions how can i do that? please help me. @stephanh